# How to relate those two Enum?

Tags: python

I chose to use `Enum` to define an immutable, related set of constant values.

```py
from enum import Enum
import attr
class Status(Enum):
    done:str = "done"
    not_done:str = "not done"

class Reason(Enum):
    unsufficient_time: "insufficient time"
    unsufficient_staff: "unsufficient staff"

@attr.dataclass(frozen=True)
class TaskInfo:
    status: Status = Status
    reason: Reason = Reason
```

The problem is that I don't want it to be exactly like that. Indeed, I only care about `Reason` **only if the `Status` is `not_done`**.

I am a little bit confused, I don't know how to relate them in an elegant way.

Comment: for starters, this is wrong: `status: Status = Status` etc is wrong... you are assigning the *class* `Status` instead of an instance, that's like saying `number: int = int`... you want `status: Status = Status.not_done` or whatever... in any case, I am not exactly sure what you are asking. What do you mean "how to relate them"? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is a product type. This is not the right model for this. Consider the following Haskell code (which I think does the best job of expressing this concept)

```hs
data Reason = NoTime | NoStaff
data Status = Done | NotDone Reason

data Task = Task
  { name   :: String
  , status :: Status
  }
```

This is equivalent to saying that a task is a union of a String (name) and a Status. There are two reasons, `NoTime` and `NoStaff` (that's basically an enum). Also there are two statuses, `Done` and `NotDone Reason`. The latter is how we differentiate from your code -- you cannot be Done with a reason, and you cannot be NotDone without a reason. This fails at the type level.

There's no great support in Python for this, but you could hack it together in logic:

```py
class Reason(Enum):
    NoTime = "no time"
    NoStaff = "no staff"

class Status(Enum):
    def __init__(self, reason=None):
        self.reason = reason

    Done = None
    NotDone_Staff = Reason.NoStaff
    NotDone_Time = Reason.NoTime
```

But keep in mind that while Haskell handles this with type constructors, here you've created two separate concrete types `Status.NotDone_Staff` and `Status.NotDone_Time`.

Comment: What's the role of  `def __init__` here ?

Comment: @JoffreyL. that's the constructor